# application/xml selected by default in Response content type dropdown

Tags: spring, rest, swagger-ui, springfox

My REST controller is annotated with `@RequestMapping(produces = { APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })` and when a client sends `Accept: */*` it returns JSON. If I change the order in the annotation it returns XML.

However, on the generated swagger-ui site ( `http://localhost/swagger-ui.html#/` ) `application/xml` is always selected by default in the "Response content type" dropdown. How can I change the default to `application/json`?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/version", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
public class VersionFacadeREST {
    @GetMapping
    public StringMessage getVersion() { ... }
}

public class StringMessage {
    private String message;
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(final String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you have a yaml file, try reordering them there also